# JavaScript Alternative for Zoom in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

In most browsers we can use JavaScript zoom except Firefox

How to do the similar function exactly by JavaScript in Firefox?

Scale or transform won't zoom instead adds extra space and not serves my purpose

Also -moz-transform or scale does not behave the same as zoom. It crops out the elements instead of enlarging everything but keeping them within view
which I dont want

```js
document.body.style.zoom = 0.5;
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/19/00/18/splashing-165192_960_720.jpg" alt="Image Unavailable">
```

Comment: The snippet with simple image is for example I used zoom for complex div and zoom only serves my purpose

Comment: [`zoom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom) is not defined in any standard, so whether it works or not is completely up to the browser vendor. Apparently Mozilla has decided not to implement a non-standard in Firefox.

Comment: Yeah I know need a similar approach which can do my thing

Comment: If you follow the link in my previous comment, MDN's article on the subject discusses using `transform: scale()` but you've already said that does not serve your purpose. Since the `zoom` property is only defined by an [unofficial draft proposal](https://cdn.rawgit.com/atanassov/css-zoom/master/Overview.html), and the algorithm there is quite involved, I think this a bit much to ask of people volunteering their time. If you wanted to start writing the code, and come to us with specific questions as you worked on it, I think that would be the better route.

Comment: The thing is zoom enlarges the element but scale crops out it dont behaves as zoom.Need a alternative which behaves as same similar to zoom